# Right way to verify with Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I have a method - 
getSomethingAmount()  in some class (class A) I want to test. This 
getSomethingAmount() method logic depends on Set bSet, which is 
passed in constructor on class A initialization.  For example if 
Set bSet contains of 2 objects with Status.OK, when getSomethingAmount() must 
return 2. How can I correctly verify this condition with 
Mockito ?

Now I stub 2 B class type objects, put them into bSet and then assert 
getSomethingAmount() method result with JUnit assertion - it works, 
but it doesn't looks to me like "true" Mockito way.

Answer (score 1):

From your description of the expected behaviour, it sounds like at pretty solid way to unit test the method. By the "true Mockito way" I suppose what you want is something like:

```
Set mockBSet = mock(Set.class);
stub(mockBSet.size()).toReturn(2);
A testObjectA = new A(mockBSet);
Assert.assertEquals(testObjectA.getSomethingAmount(), 2);
```

This is under the assumption, that the initialisation of the Set and test objects does not have any side effects, which you want the test to take into account. (E.g. always adds some default "somethings".) In which case, you can also leave out the stubbing and assert the method under test returns a value equals to the size of the set.

Answer (score 1):

Mock the objects in the collection, not the collection. Otherwise the test will be fragile and break if you change the implementation. For instance if you decide you need to loop through your objects in the Set, instead of just using the size-method.

```
B b = mock(B.class);
A target = new A(new HashSet<B>(Arrays.asList(b, b)));
Assert.assertSame(2, target.getSomethingAmount());
```